# Bulk read from Excel Cells and organize under dot notation (value = header1.header2)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm wondering if this is possible in Excel. Users will enter their items in the following way:

[image]

I'll be looping through these IDs to do multiple things, so I'd need them to be readable by multiple subs. I'm wondering how I could effectively read all this in at once and then be able to refer as IDNumber.Category1 where that return Id 1's Category 1 value.
Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense. What are the users entering;; categories?  It would  be helpful if you included some sample data that is *representative* of the actual data, as well as the code that you have tried so far, and an explanation of what's going wrong with it, and where.  Please see "[ask]" as well as how to include a [mcve].  More good tips [here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Answer (score 0):

Read to array. Then use the notation myarray(category [as long], id [as long])

```
Dim r as variant
r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.value ' read into array

Dim id as long
Dim cat as long
id = 1
cat = 1
debug.print r(cat, id) ' read by index [in this case (cat = 1, id = 1)]
'also worth noting that the max cat will be = ubound(r)
'              and that the max id  will be = ubound(r,2)
```

Additionally you can then read the elements of the array into a collection of collections (2 layers) or a dictionary of dictionaries (again 2 layers) in order to refer to it by name as `value = dict(id)(category)`.

In order to have the variable containing the data accessible to multiple subs you'll want to declare it outside the function (ie. on the top lines of the module) and declare as private (available for subs on that module only) or public (available for subs in all modules on that workbook).

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are trying to get in the format of delimited by dot, the values entered by a user for a given category. To simplify, the table may be depicted as below:

[image]

If that's the case, you can run a simple query to organize result in dot notation like below. In case you are looking for something else, feel free to clarify.

```
Sub usrVal()
    Dim usrInpt As Long, i1 As Long, i2 As Long, lastRw As Long, lastCol As Long, rslt As String
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    lastRw = Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
    lastCol = Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column
    usrInpt = InputBox("Enter the category number to retrive data")
    For i1 = 2 To lastRw
        If Cells(i1, 1) = "Category " & usrInpt Then
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 1) = "Category " & usrInpt
            rslt = Cells(i1, 2)
            For i2 = 3 To lastCol
                rslt = rslt & "." & Cells(i1, i2)
            Next i2
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 2) = rslt
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i1
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
End Sub
```

**Result** for input = 9:
Cell A2: `Category 9`
Cell B2: `data9.data26.data43.data60.data77.data94.data111`

**Assumptions**: data is in Sheet1, macro runs from Sheet2, and writes the result their in cells A2 & A3.

Comment: It's readability, I'm looking for it to be a global sub that I can call by id then attribute in other subs. The id is just as important as the data for identification.

Comment: the code arranges data delimited by dot for a particular category, to which id can easily be added with a little bit of tweak, provided the requirements are clear. for example you might be looking for all IDs & data for a particular category to be presented like id1.data1, id2.data18, etc. if you still need help, pl clarify with an example of what info you'll feed and what info you'll need against that.